# Error: system call size not allowed in this dialect use system Verilog mode in Vivado

Tags: size, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I have a piece of Verilog code here

```
$size(data);
```

where `data` is a  16-bit number.

But, it gives an error in Vivado.

```
error: system call size not allowed in this dialect use system Verilog mode
```

I have tried searching for a solution, but no luck, hence posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that the `$size` system function can only be used if SystemVerilog features are enabled in Vivado.  One way to do so is to give your files a `.sv` extension.